# iphone; converting lat,long strings to floats - or any other method?

Tags: xcode, floating-accuracy

Hi there
i have a string something like "3.1600559280405984" which is a latitude value. When i want to convert this into a float value, to assign to an annotation/coordinate, the floatValue of the string returns truncated 3.160056, how can i get the complete float without losing the decimals? 
Or is there some other way i could assign strings to coordinates?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `float` has more precision than that.  It's just being displayed with fewer decimal points.

You could use `printf` or an Objective-C equivalent to print it with more decimal points.  Note that some of those may be false precision, due to binary floating point issues.

You can use `double` for a bit more precision.

Also, note that your input probably has false precision to begin with.